# R Download financial information of German (DAX) companies with quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod, financial, stockquotes

I would like to download the financial data of companies listed in Germany and possibly of other countries. There is the package [quantmod](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/quantmod.pdf) and the example works perfectly

```
getFinancials('GE')
viewFinancials(GE.f)
GE.f$IS$A
```

I would like to download the information for German companies for example Volkswagen. The stock code VOW does not work directly, I think because it is listed in Frankfurt. Is there something else that I need to enter to download this dataset?

Comment: `getFinancials` uses Google Finance which does not provide financials for stocks listed in Germany.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to get the financials of German companies?